# Unit test for OS patching process in RHEL

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade, software-updates, testing

As a part of my automation framework, I am using ansible to perform the OS patching to my host machines. Before executing this proccess in production, I need to write a unit test to verifiy that, the task:

```
yum update
```

is finishing successfully.

I am trying to get the number of packages that will be updated and compare it, after, with the number of packages that has been updated (using this command: `yum history`.

What is the best way?

> Note: the test will run beforehand on a similar testing machine (RHEL 7)